# Using mx.charts in a Flex mobile project

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, charts, flex4.5, flex4.6

Adobe states that [Charts are supported in mobile projects](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile_development_hero_burrito.html) but when I try to change the following working files (created project with File - New - Flex Mobile Project - Google Nexus One):

MyTest.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MobileApplication 
      xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      firstView="views.MyTestHome">
 <s:navigationContent>
  <s:Button label="Home"
     click="navigator.popToFirstView();"/>
 </s:navigationContent>

 <s:actionContent/>
</s:MobileApplication>
```

MyTestHome.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
  title="Test Chart">
</s:View>
```

to the new MyTestHome.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
  title="Test Chart">

 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import mx.collections.*;

   [Bindable]
   private var medalsAC:ArrayCollection = 
    new ArrayCollection( [
    {Country: "USA", Gold: 35, Silver:39, Bronze: 29 },
    {Country:"China", Gold: 32, Silver:17, Bronze: 14 },
    {Country:"Russia", Gold: 27, Silver:27, Bronze: 38 } 
   ]);
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>

 <mx:PieChart id="chart" height="100%" width="100%"
     paddingRight="5" paddingLeft="5" color="0x323232"
     dataProvider="{medalsAC}" >

  <mx:series>
   <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" field="Gold">
    <mx:calloutStroke>
     <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0" 
        color="0x888888" alpha="1.0"/>
    </mx:calloutStroke>
    <mx:radialStroke>
     <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0" 
        color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0.20"/>
    </mx:radialStroke>
    <mx:stroke>
     <s:SolidColorStroke color="0" 
        alpha="0.20" weight="2"/>
    </mx:stroke>
   </mx:PieSeries>
  </mx:series>
 </mx:PieChart> 
</s:View>
```

and also add

- c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash
  Builder Burrito\sdks\4.5.0\frameworks\libs\datavisualization.swc
- c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Burrito\sdks\4.5.0\frameworks\libs\sparkskins.swc
- c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Burrito\sdks\4.5.0\frameworks\libs\mx\mx.swc

to Flex Build Path (clicking "Add SWC" button):

[image]

Then it fails with the error:

**Could not resolve  to a component implementation.**

Does anybody please have an idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay got this working, here's what I have setup, using the default Hero SDK that comes with Flash Builder Burrito I was able to ultimately get this working I also tested with the Hero 17689 build and it appears to be working fine as well.  You only need the two swcs imported from the 4.5.0\frameworks\libs folders the mx.swc and the datavisualization.swc.  After adding these two I also needed to correct the namespaces in order to get it to be recognized and build and run.
[image]

TestMobileApp.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.TestMobileAppHome">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:MobileApplication>
```

TestMobileAppHome.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:charts="mx.charts.*"
    xmlns:series="mx.charts.series.*"
    xmlns:chartClasses="mx.charts.chartClasses.*" 
    title="Test Chart">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.charts.PieChart;
        import mx.collections.*;

        [Bindable]
        private var medalsAC:ArrayCollection = 
            new ArrayCollection( [
                {Country: "USA", Gold: 35, Silver:39, Bronze: 29 },
                {Country:"China", Gold: 32, Silver:17, Bronze: 14 },
                {Country:"Russia", Gold: 27, Silver:27, Bronze: 38 } 
            ]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<charts:PieChart id="chart" height="100%" width="100%"
                 paddingRight="5" paddingLeft="5" color="0x323232"
                 dataProvider="{medalsAC}" >

    <charts:series>
        <series:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" field="Gold">
            <series:calloutStroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0" 
                                    color="0x888888" alpha="1.0"/>
            </series:calloutStroke>
            <series:radialStroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0" 
                                    color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0.20"/>
            </series:radialStroke>
            <series:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0" 
                                    alpha="0.20" weight="2"/>
            </series:stroke>
        </series:PieSeries>
    </charts:series>
</charts:PieChart>
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll test it tomorrow. How do you install a newer Hero SDK? Greetings from Germany

Comment: Took a bit of searching but found it for download here: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero you just get the zip and extract it to some folder then in Flash Builder/Eclipse in Window->Preferences->Flash Builder->Installed Flex SDKS hit the add button and browse to the folder where you extracted everything, I usually keep it all in the sdks folder within the flash builder install folder just to keep things tidy.

Comment: Could you add the header for the TestMobileAppHome.mxml view please? I still get the error: The prefix "charts" for element "charts:PieChart" is not bound.

Comment: Sorry the code button in SO isn't always friendly with me, it was in there just not being shown, looks good to me now let me know if you still can't see or are hung up.