# How to draw pie chart in flex4(fiex mobile project) in playbook?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I'm able to draw filled circle eith ellipse-spark primitive, now I'm unable to draw lines in circle for given angles.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:
[Using mx.charts in a Flex mobile project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531751/using-mx-charts-in-a-flex-hero-mobile-project)